Chrome lagging issue in Ubuntu 24.04
I had installed Chrome on my Ubuntu 24.04 laptop that has 4GB RAM, but Chrome was lagging. All the other browsers were working fine except Chrome. I have downloaded the .deb file of Chrome from the official website. I tried to reinstall it many times, but it still was very laggy.

@guiverc Ubuntu 24.04 LTS

@karel I already used Chrome on my laptop in a different Linux distro but there I was not able to notice lag. Chrome in Ubuntu only has a lagging issue on my laptop. By the way, I have 4 GB of RAM and I think it was enough for Chrome because Brave is working fine which is based on Chromium with lot of extra features.

Anyone help me ?

If you are facing lag even when you have a single tab, it's not because of low RAM. Try disabling "Use hardware acceleration when available" in the settings. You can try disabling extensions one by one and check the performance.

I have the same issue. Regret installing 24 and was the final straw after 5 years on Ubuntu. Disabling hardware acceleration is no a solution as apps like Figma will not work.
